# mysql | Getting Database error, Invalid Use of Group Function

Tags: mysql, sql

i am using ignited datatables. it is working fine except for the filter. when i do searching in it, i get error

> Invalid Use of group function

i am getting this query in error result.

```
SELECT `f`.`FormID`, `f`.`FormName`, `f`.`FormCIPath`, 
MIN(g.IsMenuLink) AS IsMenuLink, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.GroupID ORDER BY g.GroupID) AS GroupIDs 
FROM (`sys_forms` f) INNER JOIN `sys_forms_in_groups` g ON `g`.`FormID` = `f`.`FormID` 
WHERE `g`.`GroupID` IN ('1', '1') AND (UPPER(f.FormName) LIKE '%DA%' OR 
UPPER(f.FormCIPath) LIKE '%DA%' OR UPPER(MIN(g.IsMenuLink)) LIKE '%DA%' ) 
GROUP BY `f`.`formID` LIMIT 25
```

what is wrong with the query.??

Comment: Just a side note: Be aware that LIMIT gives you 25 random forms, as you don't use an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Ooh, ugly. You can't use MIN in that way (WHERE MIN()), although you could use HAVING isntead - but what are you actually trying to do? And are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation !?!?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner GROUP BY establishes an implicit (and consistent) order

Comment: @Strawberry: Okay, this is something special then in MySQL. In standard SQL you would always need ORDER BY to guarantee a sort order.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm not too familiar with other dialects - but it seems to work the same... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7f99/1

Comment: @yes, i know its the query generated by ignited datatables.. need to fix it now.. but i am not sure how.. 
yes i am using sensitive collation. if i dont use UPPER then i will have case sensitive issue on my hands

Comment: @Strawberry: GROUP BY often happens to result in ordered output in other dbms, but that's not guaranteed, and I have often seen unordered results in spite of GROUP BY. MySQL even admits that GROUP BY sorting can be extra work which can be avoided by using ORDER BY NULL here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have aggregation functions in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT `f`.`FormID`, `f`.`FormName`, `f`.`FormCIPath`, MIN(g.IsMenuLink) AS IsMenuLink, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.GroupID ORDER BY g.GroupID) AS GroupIDs
FROM (`sys_forms` f) INNER JOIN
     `sys_forms_in_groups` g
     ON `g`.`FormID` = `f`.`FormID`
WHERE `g`.`GroupID` IN ('1', '1') AND
       (UPPER(f.FormName) LIKE '%DA%' OR
        UPPER(f.FormCIPath) LIKE '%DA%' OR
        UPPER(MIN(g.IsMenuLink)) LIKE '%DA%'
--------------^
       )
GROUP BY `f`.`formID`
LIMIT 25;
```

You can simply remove the function, I think:

```
WHERE `g`.`GroupID` IN ('1', '1') AND
       (UPPER(f.FormName) LIKE '%DA%' OR
        UPPER(f.FormCIPath) LIKE '%DA%' OR
        UPPER(g.IsMenuLink) LIKE '%DA%'
       )
```

Or move it to a `having` clause.

```
SELECT `f`.`FormID`, `f`.`FormName`, `f`.`FormCIPath`, MIN(g.IsMenuLink) AS IsMenuLink, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.GroupID ORDER BY g.GroupID) AS GroupIDs
FROM (`sys_forms` f) INNER JOIN
     `sys_forms_in_groups` g
     ON `g`.`FormID` = `f`.`FormID`
WHERE `g`.`GroupID` IN ('1', '1') AND
       (UPPER(f.FormName) LIKE '%DA%' OR
        UPPER(f.FormCIPath) LIKE '%DA%'
       )
GROUP BY `f`.`formID`
HAVING UPPER(MIN(g.IsMenuLink)) LIKE '%DA%'
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: Thankyou sir for reply, let me check what is the change in the query and if your query works..